# Visual Basic 2010 Date formation Multicolumn combo Grid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a multicolumn Combogrid the problem i have is Date and Time columns.
They are displayed in long format in grid but when i select them they appear in fields in correct short format. How can i change the long format in grid to short?

Comment: do you really think the above is sufficient information to diagnose the issue? VS2010 and VBA are not (directly) related so you should specify which environment you are referring to. You should also (if VB.NET as I suspect) specify which forms framework (WPF or Forms). In any event, I imagine there is a format property for said control that governs how date datatypes are displayed by default - change this explicitly in code (or IDE GUI) or XAML as needed.

Comment: This is  Visual Studio 2010 environment. The box is custom made. I tried to change it in the code but o luck. Maybe I am close.

Comment: *I tried to change it in the code*  Why don't you **show us what you've tried?**?